# Associate HTML files with Google Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android, html

I want to create a file association between my local HTML pages and Google Chrome, the reason being that I am beginning to develop HTML pages and I need to be able to access the URL address as I use this to pass parameters between HTML pages. I am hoping that when opening the HTML page in Chrome I will be able to do this, as it appears that 'HTML viewer' does not.

Answer (score 0):

When you tap on the local link, you should get an option to chose which browser to use.  If so, simply chose Google Chrome.

If you do not see this dialogue, go to Settings-Apps-html viewer and tap clear defaults.  The next time you open an HTML File(or any link), you should see the dialogue described above.

I hope your HTML development goes well!

Comment: html viewer is not included in the list of Apps (via Settings-Apps), however having installed FileExpert then when opening local html page from FileExpert I am given option to open via 'FE Text Editor' or 'HTML Viewer' (i.e. no option to open via Chrome).

Comment: This is an old answer, but I just came here with a similar question and want to add a hint. If you don't see "HTML Viewer" in settings/apps then you need to click on the 3-dot menu in the upper right corner and click "Show system apps". Then it will appear.

Answer (score 0):

From [the OP's (now deleted) comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112776/associate-html-files-with-google-chrome#comment139510_112842) (with copyedit),

> I have found a workaround for this by opening Chrome, manually typing in the address of my local HTML index page (using `file:///etc...`), and then bookmarking the page URL in Chrome & placing the bookmark on my screen, not very elegant but works for testing for now.